# Re-add lost Clickhouse replica in Zookeeper cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

We previously had three Clickhouse nodes perfectly synced within Zookeeper until one of them was lost.

The Clickhouse node was rebuilt exactly as it was before (with Ansible) and the same `create table` command was run which resulted in the following error.

Command:

```
CREATE TABLE ontime_replica ( ... )
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/ontime_replica', '{replica}', FlightDate, (Year, FlightDate), 8192)
```

The error is:

```
Received exception from server:
Code: 253. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1. DB::Exception: Replica /clickhouse/tables/01/ontime_replica/replicas/clickhouse1 already exists..
```

We're currently using Zookeeper version 3.4.10 and I would like to know if there's a way to remove the existing replica within Zookeeper, or simple let Zookeeper know that this is the new version of the existing replica.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

My approach to the solution was incorrect. Originally, I thought I needed to remove the replica within Zookeeper. Instead, the following commands within the Clickhouse server solve this problem.

- Copy the SQL file from another, working node. The file is in `/var/lib/clickhouse/metadata/default`
- `chown clickhouse:clickhouse <database>.sql`
- `chmod 0640 <database>.sql`
- `sudo -u clickhouse touch /var/lib/clickhouse/flags/force_restore_data`
- `service clickhouse-server start`

Comment: reference to the official doc: [Recovery After Complete Data Loss](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replication/#recovery-after-complete-data-loss)

Comment: it's worth noting the table definition SQLs may need adjustment depending on the zk path used for each table - e.g. marco defining zk path has a custom <replica>_suffix section with different, static "suffix" part used for each node the zk path from table SQL must match the macro value of the node being re-built.

Comment: If the re-added node was down long enough to miss any new table created on a cluster the re-added node's log should be searched for "No metadata" phrase on startup to get a list of tables without metadata in zk and each table not registered in zk by the re-added node must be registered in zk with ":) system restore replica db_name.table_name" command.